# Is there a way to use a BigQuery view as an input to dataflow?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm aware that dataflow can use a BigQuery table (or an SQL style query of a BigQuery table) for input, but is it possible to refer to a saved view as input to dataflow?

Comment: Have you tried it? Can you describe which Dataflow client/language you are using?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use bigquery legacy view in dataflow but you can't use standard sql view as it is not supported.

My suggestion is that you should use [BigQuery job](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/bigquery/QuerySample.java) to convert bigquery view to bigquery table then use it into dataflow.

Comment: Hm, can you elaborate why you think this is not supported? I haven't tried, but I'd expect that you should be able to read from a view by using BigQueryIO.read().fromQuery() with a simple SQL query that selects from the view.

Comment: Yes I tried and find that standard SQL view are not working - however standard sql is allowed using following syntax. BigQueryIO.Read
.named("ReadYearAndTemp")
.fromQuery("SELECT year, mean_temp FROM `samples.weather_stations`")
.usingStandardSql();

Answer (score 0):

You can read from Bigquery view in Dataflow. Try the Python code below:

```
beam.io.Read(
        beam.io.BigQuerySource(use_standard_sql=True,
                               query='SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.view` limit 1000000'))
```

Comment: @helin-shiah did you try this suggestion from @kyle-xiong? Did it work?